# How to manage connections when using DbModelBuilder in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, connection-pooling, irepository

I am writing an `IRepository` and `IUnitOfWork` wrapper for an EF4 Fluent schema.

In this design, a `DbCompiledModel` is created once per application lifecycle (Like an NHibernate `ISessionFactory`). The `DbCompiledModel` expects an existing database connection, as do all `DbContexts`.

This is the `DbCompiledModel` factory:

```
public class DbCompiledModelFactory
{
    public static DbCompiledModel Build(
        string mappingAssembly, DbConnection connection)
    {
        DbModelBuilder modelBuilder = new DbModelBuilder();
        AddMappingsFromAssembly(modelBuilder, mappingAssemblyName);
        DbModel model = modelBuilder.Build(connection);
        return model.Compile();
    }
}
```

Once the `DbCompiledModel` is created, a new `DbContext` can be created using `new DbContext(connection, compiledModel, true)`

So I am faced with two choices: Either share one `DbConnection` through the whole application lifecycle or create a shortlived `DbConnection` just for the model building process, and a new `DbConnection` whenever a `DbContext` is created.

Is there a more effective way of managing connections that I have overlooked?

Comment: EF caches the `DbCompiledModel` per app domin. Why do you want to duplicate that functionality?

Comment: I'd like to have the repository / unitofwork layer on top of EF because I may want to replace EF with another ORM at a later date.

Comment: you didn't answer my question. ORM replacement/switching would be a very difficult. You are wasting time on unnecessary abstractions.

Comment: To rephrase: I want to duplicate that functionality because it will make it easy to replace the ORM implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The connection itself is only needed to identify ADO.NET provider and manifest token. The `Build` method has overloaded version accepting `DbProviderInfo` instance. This overload is internally called by the overload accepting `DbConnection`. So you can call the version with `DbProviderInfo` directly if you don't like the one with `DbConnection`.

Don't use EF if you know that you will need another ORM later. Designing application to support multiple ORMs is only possible if you know uppfront all of them and design your application in the way that it uses only shared features among them. IMHO support more then one ORM is never needed and replacing ORM always means changes to application.